# How to design this html Box for legacy browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to design this box which has the following structure:

[image]

I have the following html/css which works well in ff/chrome/safari. but IE had to spoil the fun. please suggest how can i support IE?

**THE PROBLEM**
the background images are not getting displayed.

**PROBLEM BROWSER** 
IE 6,7,8,9

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/amitverma/u33aP/

```
<div id="canvasFrame">
            <img src="resources/images/canvasFrog.png" id="canvasFrog" alt="" />
            <img src="resources/images/canvasLeaves.png" id="canvasLeaves" alt="" />
            <div class="canvasContent">
            </div>
        </div>


#canvasFrame {
    background: url("../../resources/images/canvasTop.png"), url("../../resources/images/canvasBottom.png"), url("../../resources/images/canvasBg.png"), url("../../resources/images/canvasBgtexture.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y, repeat-y;
    background-position: center top, center bottom, 0 0, 10px 0;
    width: 742px; margin-top: 40px;
    min-height: 440px; 
    position: relative; 
}

#canvasFrog { position: absolute; top:-65px; left:34px; }
#canvasLeaves { bottom: -15px; position: absolute; right: -22px;  }
```

Comment: This will work perfectly: `<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/RNbq0.jpg">` :P

Comment: updated both the queries in the post above

Comment: If you recreate in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we don't have to then that is greatly appreciated. Do you mean that multiple background images aren't supported? That isn't just a problem in IE - as far as I am aware, with older browsers only Safari supported more than 1.

Comment: created in jsfiddle. yes. i understand. i wanted to know if this box can be create so that it supports the legacy browsers? i just want a box that can hold data and be structured like the image above

Comment: @amit You would need to provide a direct path to your background images for us to make sense of that [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitverma/u33aP/). However, I have added a potential solution to the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way I can see you supporting multiple background images is by adding some extra divs to your HTML and changing your CSS a bit:

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvasFrame">
    <img src="resources/images/canvasFrog.png" id="canvasFrog" alt="" />
    <img src="resources/images/canvasLeaves.png" id="canvasLeaves" alt="" />
    <div class="frame_top"></div>
    <div class="canvasContent">
        .... 
    </div>
    <div class="frame_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#canvasFrame {
    background: url("../../resources/images/canvasBgtexture.jpg") repeat-y 10px 0;;
    .....    
}

.canvasContent{
    background: url("../../resources/images/canvasBg.png") repeat-y 0 0;
    .....  
}

.frame_top {
    background: url("../../resources/images/canvasTop.png") no-repeat left top;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;   
}

.frame_bottom {
    background: url("../../resources/images/canvasBottom.png") no-repeat top left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Obviously, you would change the height of the `.frame_top` and `.frame_bottom` to reflect the dimensions of your background images.